# css horizontal menu separator not showing in IE8

Tags: html, css

The separator is showing in chrome, but not in IE8, but in design mode it does

Other issue is that the border-left of the last child (Username) that is suppose to not showing the separator is showing it.

**Chrome view:**

```
Orders | Manual Orders |                              Username
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <!-- Menu Items -->
        <li><a href="#">Orders</a></li>                              
        <li><a href="#">Manual Orders</a></li>                                               
        <!-- Username Information at the right side of the menu items  -->  
        <li style="float:right;padding-right:10px;color:#fef4f3;font-size:14px;">
            <asp:Label ID="lblUsername" runat="server" Text="Username"></asp:Label>
        </li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#navigation
{
    float: left;
    width: 960px;
    background: #656565;    
}

#navigation ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#navigation ul li
{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}

#navigation li a
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 1px 5px;
    color: #fff;    
    font-size: 14px;    
    border-right: 1px solid#fff;
}

#navigation li a:hover { 
    background: #f5625b; 
}

#navigation li:first-child a
{
    border-left: none; /*To remove first left separator*/
}

#navigation li:last-child a
{
    border-left: none; /*To remove last left separator*/
}
```

Any idea of what could be wrong here?

Comment: last-child isn't supported in IE8...

Comment: 1) try placing inline-block on #navigation ul li instead inline 2) as first-child works in IE on #navigation li a you can do like border-left:1px solid#fff;

Comment: @PravinVaichal inline-block didn't work, 2nd issue solved! thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE is very strict with spaces between values of shorthand properties. While other browsers such as Chrome and FF will parse the above just fine, IE will ignore it.

```
border-right: 1px solid#fff;
```

should be:

```
border-right: 1px solid #fff;
```